# Rails mail attachment is in e-mail body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendmail, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I need to send simple mail with an attachment. Right now it sends an email but attachment is in the e-mail body like this. 
[image]

```
--
Content-Type: text/csv;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=errors_in_address_table.csv
Content-ID: <5b0e7d6b4abff_10c12ac224c8b0d4994d@development.mail>
```

**Current code to send email**

```
saved_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'fix_db', 'errors_in_address_table.csv')
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'no-replay@test.com', to: 'test@test.com', subject: 'Errors in database', body: '', content_type: 'multipart/mixed')
mailer.attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read(saved_file) }
mailer.deliver
```

I tried to get this to work correctly for hours. Maybe some more experienced coder can help me.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "is in the E-Mail body", maybe it's confusing because your mail client show's it somehow inline? but from the EML I can say that it's stored as an attachment

Comment: @siegy22 After sending mail I receive email with this text in body section I ment.

Comment: Can you upload your E-Mail? the .eml file?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else stumbling across this, this should work (at least in Rails 6+) from the Rails console:

```rb
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.new
mailer.attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = File.read(saved_file)
mailer.mail(from: 'from@test.com', to: 'to@test.com', subject: 'Errors', body: '').deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some different bits of code for attachment in my app, I am not sure this could work for you but you may give it a try.

Try to replace your block

```
saved_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'fix_db', 'errors_in_address_table.csv')
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'no-replay@test.com', to: 'test@test.com', subject: 'Errors in database', body: '', content_type: 'multipart/mixed')
mailer.attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read(saved_file) }
mailer.deliver
```

with the following which is a bit simpler:

```
attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = open(Rails.root.join('db', 'fix_db', 'errors_in_address_table.csv')).read
mail(from: 'no-replay@test.com', to: 'test@test.com', subject: 'Errors in database', body: '')
```

This is really a trial and error approach. I will delete if it doesn't work.

Also do you have a view for your mailer ?

Comment: No, I do not have view for mailer. I needed to keep it simple as possible. Can I do it without adding view for mailer?

Answer (score -1):

As per the description shared, it seems like you need to modify attachments code

```
saved_file = Rails.root.join('db', 'fix_db', 'errors_in_address_table.csv')
mailer = ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'no-replay@test.com', to:    'test@test.com', subject: 'Errors in database', body: '', content_type: 'multipart/mixed')
mailer.attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = saved_file
mailer.deliver
```

Comment: Can you describe what you changed and why?

Comment: mailer.attachments['errors_in_address_table.csv'] = saved_file #changed this line

Comment: The API does not say anything about this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments

Comment: As stated in  http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments ,
 mail.attachments['filename.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg') 
Need to specify the file path in attachments

Comment: yes..I have also written the same things..
 mail.attachments['filename.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg')